# How to find out if my computer's hardware has the Type 1 hypervisor?

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

I just learned about 2 types of hypervisors: Type 1 which is embedded in the hardware of a computer and Type 2 which is software-based. Question: how to find out if my computer has a Type 1 hypervisor?

Comment: maybe interesting? They are different but not better? [HTG Explains: What is a Virtual Machine Hypervisor?](http://www.howtogeek.com/66734/htg-explains-what-is-a-hypervisor/). Also: [Type 2 client hypervisors aren't worse than Type 1, just different](http://searchvirtualdesktop.techtarget.com/feature/Type-2-client-hypervisors-arent-worse-than-Type-1-just-different)

Comment: Ah ok. I was thinking that Type 1 should be better.

Comment: As did I until just now. :)

Answer (score 2):

No hypervisor is embedded in hardware. Hypervisor is a software that provides virtualization of underlying hardware either by using hardware virtualization extensions or completely in software. The type of hypervisor is determined by the location of its implementation. Hypervisor can be bare metal (type 1) or it can be hosted on operating system. type 1 hypervisors are VMware ESI, Xen(open source) while  KVM is hosted by Linux so it is type 2 hypervisor. Usually type 2 hypervisors are also termed Vitual Machine Monitor (VMM).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are within a Windows VM. Use MSINFO32.

Comment: Please elaborate and explain your answer properly.